# StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape '\:' not one of [\b, \t, \n, \f, \r, \\, \", \'] when creating an HTML string body

Tags: string, scala

On user sign up, I want to send an email with `html` body to user. I have created the email template as follows:

```
object EmailHTML {
  val body =
    s"""
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]-->
...
""".stripMargin
}
```

And I am using it like:

```
val html = if(userToken.tokenType == UserTokenType.RegistrationConfirmation){
        EmailHTML.body 
      }else {
        EmailHTML.body 
      }
SignupEmail(subject,from,html)
```

When I execute the code, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape '\:' not one of [\b, \t, \n, \f, \r, \\, \", \'] at index 454 in "
       |<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>
    ...
```

The exception doesn't occur if I remove the line:

```
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]-->
```

But the email I receive is not well formatted! What might be the issue and what is the importance of the line?

```
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution you might find helpful is removing the `s` before `"""`:

```scala
val body1 = """
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]-->
...""".stripMargin
```

It will cause the string not to be evaluated, and therefore it will stay as is.

Code running at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BBBfnao4QmiRBbh2FoDPHg).

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding extra `\` i.e changed `o\:` to `o\\:` and in other places. I think the solution was trivial, was just not thinking straight